# Вызов приложения из другого приложения

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте! Есть приложение, например видео плеер, нужно сделать так что бы оно появилось в списке "открыть с помощью приложения "..."", желательно что бы оно появлялось в списке когда я непосредственно пытаюсь открыть видео файл.
Гуглил, но так ничего понятного и не нагуглил, дело в том что я совсем даже представляю как сформировать запрос. Пробовал манипулировать с манифестом, а именно добавлял в интент фильтры: category (SEND, DEFAULT), и в data (video/*, mg4). Но так ничего и не получилось. Такое ощущение, что чего-то не хватает.

Comment: @Покажите более подробно, что что вы пробовали. На какой версии Android вы это тестировали?

Comment: <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.SEND"/>
                <data android:mimeType="video/*"/>
            </intent-filter>

Comment: Android 7.1.2, портированная прошивка на Lenovo s650 "resurrection remix", ядро 3,4,67 (если я всё правильно понимаю).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
<activity android:name=".VideoPlayer" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/BlackHolo" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="rtsp" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/sdp" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Отлично всё работает, спасибо. Может кому понадобиться:   
 Intent intent = getIntent(); // получаем интент  Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(intent.getDataString()); //получаем ссылку, при условии что мы точно знаем что получаем.    Минимум кода отлично подойдут для понимания принципа работы.